# How to recursively update a table with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that selects some data in a different format from my original table:

```
USE [VolTracker]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @offset int

SET @offset = 5

WHILE @offset >= 1 BEGIN
    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_getStats]
            @Doffset = @offset,
            @StartTime = --Some Datetime,
            @EndTime = --Some later Datetime,
            @Contract = NULL

    SET @offset = @offset - 1
END

GO
```

This specific example selects all 5 of the tables that I would like it to properly.  However, I would like all of these tables joined into one table.  How might I go about doing this?

Comment: "stored procedure that selects some data in a different format from my original table" sounds like a view description to me.  And MOST of the time a loop to do something in SQL can likely be done differently/better using sets - there are rare exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table variable that matches the schema of the resultset returned by sp_getStats.  Then, insert into this variable within your loop:

```
...
declare @Stage table (YourColumn1 varchar(10), YourColumn2 int, ...);

WHILE @offset >= 1 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Stage
        EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_getStats]
                @Doffset = @offset,
                @StartTime = --Some Datetime,
                @EndTime = --Some later Datetime,
                @Contract = NULL

    SET @offset = @offset - 1
END

select * from @Stage;
```

The above will work to return the union of all the resultsets returned, however if its possible for you to modify the procedure (or create a new one) that can return the complete set without a loop then I would suggest doing do.

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary table or table variable and insert into table each time you execute the stored procedure. Check [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/23/sql-server-insert-values-of-stored-procedure-in-table-use-table-valued-function/) out.

```
//declare your #temptable here

WHILE @offset >= 1 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tempTable
    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_getStats]
            @Doffset = @offset,
            @StartTime = --Some Datetime,
            @EndTime = --Some later Datetime,
            @Contract = NULL

    SET @offset = @offset - 1
END
```